# PHP min() but not empty

Tags: php, function, min

How would you best write a function to select `min()` in PHP, but ignoring empty values?

```
function minvar($var1,$var2) {
    $min=min($var1,$var2);
    return $min;
}
```

I know you could do it with `if` etc, but I thought there would be an more elegant way?

Comment: Define "empty"? When dealing with numbers there's no such thing as empty.

Comment: @TomvanderWoerdt: you are right... well, if a variable is not defined? Or has no value? Correct me if I am wrong, but in php you do not define a variable upfront as integer or string, and you can easily assign a number to a variable that has been a string before, no?

Comment: You shouldn't be passing a nonexistent variable to a function, not even in PHP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
function($var1,$var2) {
  return min($var1 ?: PHP_INT_MAX, $var2 ?: PHP_INT_MAX);
}
```

Note, that it will treat `0` as "undefined" too.

Update: When all values are empty `PHP_INT_MAX` is returned. In this implementation it is intended, because the OP explictely ask to ignore empty values. Therefore when *all* values are ignored the minimum value is in fact the overall maximum (somehow). My main intention is to keep the return value strict: When the method says to ignore empty values it would be unexpected, that in *some* cases it still return `null` nonetheless.

Comment: This can work for most situations... but if var1 and var2 are both null, you'll get  PHP_INT_MAX, not null.

Comment: @Ray Thats indeed an issue. On the other hand the OP wants the minimum value _ignoring_ the empty ones, thus when _all_ values are empty all should be ignored and the behaviour is kindof undefined, which could be represented by the `PHP_INT_MAX`. Thats somehow the "minimal value from none", which is the overall maximum (the one _every_ value is less than)

Answer (score 6):

I guess you could do it with `array_filter`:

```
function($var1,$var2) {
    $min=min(array_filter(array($var1,$var2)));
    return $min;
}
```

`array_filter` removes all items from the array that evaluate to boolean `false`. `min` then gets the lowest item from the array. Note that `0` will be removed.

Comment: I'm not able to control the number of elements my array receives, so a simple function to strip empty values, is critical.  This solution was perfect.

Comment: it will throw an error if both var1 and var2 are falsy.

Answer (score 1):

King Crunch's method does not work with non-integer types like DateTime objects. The code below does:

```
function minnotnull($var1, $var2) {
    if($var1 === null) { return $var2; } 
    if($var2 === null) { return $var1; } 
    return min($var1, $var2); 
}    

function maxnotnull($var1, $var2) {
    if($var1 === null) { return $var2; } 
    if($var2 === null) { return $var1; } 
    return max($var1, $var2); 
}
```

(be careful to use triple equality ===)